# Has anyone used XBlog module in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-mvc

Looking for a module for blogging in Sitecore 7.5 mvc, I found XBlog. Would anybody be able to compare and contrast it with WeBlog module? I see WeBlog was supported until 7.0 and I know it's based on webforms and XBlog seems like a fairly new module but supports 7.5 mvc.

Comment: Would be great for the community to support the existing WeBlog module and help us update it to 7.5, add MVC support, etc etc. It's an open source project on GitHub that anyone is free to contribute to!

Comment: I agree Nick. I was looking to use WeBlog along side MVC implementation on this project but because of a tight deadline I was looking to see if there was an alternative available.

Answer (score 1):

XBlog works with Sitecore 7 - 8 (although it requires a few tweaks for version 8) and both WebForms and MVC.

Other than that, they offer very similar features(Blog posts, author pages, search / filtering modules, and a WordPress Importer).

Version 1.1 of XBlog should be released this spring and will include Comments and shared code on github.

If you want to see how it works on a live site, you can look here:  http://www.xcentium.com/blog